# Same instance for both resolves (where one is named at registration)

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I got the following test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestTwoInterfacesOneNamed()
    {
        _container.RegisterType<MyTestClass, MyTestClass>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        _container.RegisterType(typeof(ITestClass), typeof(MyTestClass));
        _container.RegisterType(typeof(IStartable), typeof(MyTestClass), "nameSoThatAllStartablesCanBeFetched");
        var resolveAll = _container.ResolveAll<IStartable>();
        Assert.AreSame(_container.Resolve(typeof(ITestClass)), resolveAll.First());
    }
```

How do I get the same instance for both resolves? The trick with registering the concrete first works for all interfaces as long as they are not named. I do NOT want to register an instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done like this:

```
        Func<IUnityContainer, object> resolver = (unity) => unity.Resolve(typeof(MyTestClass));
        _container.RegisterType(typeof(IStartable), 
            typeof(MyTestClass), 
            "nameSoThatAllStartablesCanBeFetched", 
            new InjectionFactory(resolver));
```

Comment: Note for modern users - use `container.RegisterFactory` instead of the deprecated `InjectionFactory`.